# How to convert object type to Int with SqlReader in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I have model class course :

```
public int CourseID { get; set; }
public string CourseName { get; set; }
public int CourseCredit { get; set; }
```

and i have the following code to retrive information about Course from database:

```
List<Course> CourseList = new List<Course>();
            var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\A\Documents\CourseDB.mdf;" +
               @"Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            con.Open();
            var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select Courses.CourseID, Courses.CourseName, Courses.CourseCredit from Courses inner join UsersCourses on " +
                "[Courses].[CourseID] = [UsersCourses].[CourseID] where UsersCourses.UserID = @user", con);
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = UserID;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                {
                    CourseList.Add(new Course()
                    {
                        CourseID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CourseID"]),
                        CourseName = (reader["CouorseName"].ToString()),
                        CourseCredit = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CourseCredit"])
                    });
                }
            }
```

the problem is that there is FormatException throw when i run the code here:

```
 CourseList.Add(new Course()
                        {
                            CourseID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CourseID"]),
                            CourseName = (reader["CouorseName"].ToString()),
                            CourseCredit = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CourseCredit"])
                        });
```

any idea about how to solve it ?

Comment: Have you debugged to see what value from one of those 3 fields it doesnt like?

Comment: There's a typo. You wrote "CouorseName" instead of "CourseName"

Comment: You should look at what a [FormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is.  It can be called "in a call to a method that converts a string to some other data type, the string doesn't conform to the required pattern".  Have you debugged to see what the values of your reader has before you're converting to int?

Comment: add the table schema of the `Courses` table to the question, so the data types of the `CourseID` and `CourseCredit` columns can be seen. Maybe `CourseCredit` contains NULLs?

Comment: To make an absolute guess - one of those 2 fields you're converting to an int is nullable and has a null in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this work for me when i use reader.get method like this:

```
CourseList.Add(new Course()
                {
                    CourseID = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    CourseName = reader.GetString(1),
                    CourseCredit = reader.GetInt32(2)
                });
```

but i guess it will only work if you know exactly what your database table columns, hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try use such extension method:

```
public static int? GetInt32OrNull(this SqlDataReader reader, int index)
{
    SqlInt32 value = reader.GetSqlInt32(index);
    if (value.IsNull)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return value.Value;
}
```